# npm twigjs error when compiling template with twig functionality

Tags: node.js, npm, twig, webpack-dev-server

I have made a boilerplate for working with twig under webpack and nodejs

It can be found here: [My Twig boilerplate](https://github.com/IgorSzyporyn/twig-boilerplate)

It works ok when just iterating and using if as example, but the second I wish to use some twig functionality like "merge" (as in example) I get thrown a compile error.

The first error on compile is:

```
build modulesError compiling twig template /home/isj/Boilerplate/twig-boilerplate/src/app/twig/test.html.twig: TwigException: Unable to parse 'test = test|merge([3])'
```

And later on webpack tells me that:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

Now I recognize this error as being a JSON.parse(undefined) error.

There are some more errors to the last one, you can see that by cloning my git repo and run "npm start"

But I can not for the life of me understand why this functionality does not work since (supposedly) all twig functionality should work out of the box.

Here some reference URL's

1. [npm twig-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twig-loader)
2. [npm twig(js)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twig)

I gathered that twig-loader has twigjs as a dependency so added that.

Really hope someone can help me, if I am being unclear then please ask for more specific directions and I will answer.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the variable to another variable instead of itself worked